# Error message when creating ggplot with recession bands

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a dataset which plots unemployment over time, and I want to add in bands highlighting when there is a recession.

The original dataframe is called quarterly data.

```
recession <- data.frame(date_start= as_date(c("1973-07-01", "1980-01-01", "1990-07-01","2008-04-01")),
                        date_end = as_date(c("1975-07-01","1981-04-01", "1991-07-01","2009-04-01")))

recession$date_start <- ymd (recession$date_start)
recession$date_end <- ymd (recession$date_end)


ggplot(quarterly_data, aes(x=date, y= Unemployment))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_rect(data = recession, inherit.aes=FALSE , aes(xmin = date_start, xmax = date_end, ymin = -0.1, ymax = 0.1),
            fill = "red", alpha= 0.3)
```

However, when I run the ggplot, I get this error message:

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Without example data, it is impossible to recreate your issue. From the error it seems like you need to convert the dates in `recession` to POSIXct-format. Please try with `as.POSIXct()`

Answer (score 1):

While you have supplied us with the data frame `recession`, you have not supplied us with the data frame `quarterly_data`, where you are getting the error.  A few pointers here to try, but first, a bit of description of what to gauge is causing this issue.

First of all, `time_trans` [appears to be from the scales package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/time_trans), but it's not clear why that needs to run based on the code above.  Is there anything else that could be using the `scales` package here?

Now for the error message itself, it requires an object of class `POSIXct` only.  This is different than objects of class `Date`, which are created from the `lubridate` package that you are using, as apparent from the use of `as_date` to create the `recession` data frame.

You can confirm this yourself by running `class(recession$date_start)`, where you can see the output is a `Date` class object.

After the `ymd()` function, you are also getting an object of class `Date`.  [From the documentation](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html), you should be able to coerce the class to be converted to `POSIXct` `POSIXt` via supplying a `tz=` (time zone) argument.  You can see this with the following:

```
> class(ymd(recession$date_start))
[1] "Date"

> class(ymd(recession$date_start, tz='GMT'))
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

So, that might fix your problem.  But, you still have some detective work to do, since we don't have your other data frame and we apparently are not seeing a function that is trying to call `time_trans` from the `scales` package.  The other possibility here is that `ggplot` is calling this to adjust an axis based on a POSIXt object... but I don't see a `scale_` call or `coord_flip()` that might cause this error.  I would recommend the following sequence:

- Try the "homerun" approach by running your `ymd()` functions again, but supplying `tz="GMT"` to force the output to be a POSIXct object.  Not sure if this will be successful.
- run the `ggplot()` line itself.  Do you get the same error?  If so, the error lies within the `quarterly_data` data frame, and not the `recession` data frame.  If it works, then run the `ggplot()` line and add in the `geom_line()` object.  If it still works, then your issue is with the `geom_rect` function, which likely means the `recession` data frame.
- Check the class of date objects in `quarterly_data`.  Are they `Date` class or `POSIXct` class?  If `Date`, try to convert them to `POSIXct` (maybe just use `as.POSIXct()`).
- Is there more code that belongs here from your plot call?  If you have `coord_flip()` or any `scale_x` or other thematic elements that are added to your plot code, they can definitely be trying to adjust the time scale and result in that error.